# How can I trim the contents of a text file?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, whitespace

I want to remove all "blank" characters from the very beginning and the very end of a text file, including \n if exists. (basically mimicking the behaviour of trim() function of most programming languages, if the "file" was a big string).

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the contents of the file?

Comment: Well, any file with spaces/tabs/LF in the beginning and/or ending of a file.

Comment: Each line, or just the very beginning and end?

Comment: Just on the definition tack, I believe POSIX requires a newline at the end of a file in order to be called a “text” file. Just FYI.

Comment: Jeff:  the very beginning and end. (main description updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -z 's/^\s*//; s/\s*$//' infile
```

- `s/^\s*//`, deletes whitespaces/empty lines at very begging of the `infile` as a input file.
- `s/\s*$//`, deleted whitespaces/empty lines at very end of the `infile` as a input file including `\n` at very end of `infile`.

Example `cat -e infile`:

```
$
$
$
Three blank lines above$
$
$
Two blank lines in the middle$
a blank lines below$
$
a line with trailing whitespaces                $
          a line with leading whitespaces$
below are two empty lines + one whitespaces then an empty line again$
$
$
                                    $
$
```

The output:

```
Three blank lines above


Two blank lines in the middle
a blank lines below

a line with trailing whitespaces
          a line with leading whitespaces
below are two empty lines + one whitespaces then an empty line again
```

---

Or you can use `printf` to print the result of `sed` that removed very first whitespaces/empty lines and used it within command substitution that deletes empty lines only at very end and `\n`.

```
printf '%s' "$(sed -z 's/^\s*//' infile)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to remove *all* spaces and newlines, not just the last newline, you can use `tr`:

```
tr -d '[[:space:]]' < file > file.trimmed
```

Or, more precisely:

```
tr -d '\t\n ' < file > file.trimmed
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, not shell script, but I wrote a PHP solution:

script name: **trimfile.php**

```
<?php
if ( (!empty($argv[1])) && (file_exists($argv[1])) )  {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
    $new_file_contents = trim($file_contents) . "\n";
    if ($file_contents <> $new_file_contents) {
        file_put_contents($argv[1], $new_file_contents);
    }
}
?>
```

Usage:

```
$ php trimfile.php yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove leading/trailing whitespace *for each line* and not the file as a whole.

A test file, where some lines have leading or trailing whitespace, and blank lines:

```
$ cat -e file
line 1$
  line 2$
line 3 has trailing spaces   $
$
blank line above$
```

And a GNU sed command to do the trimming

```
$ sed -r 's/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; /^$/d' file | cat -e
line 1$
line 2$
line 3 has trailing spaces$
blank line above$
```

Answer (score 0):

In `awk`:

```
                 { isblank = 0 }
/^[[:blank:]]*$/ { isblank = 1 }

state == 0 &&  isblank { next }
state == 0 && !isblank { state = 1 }

state == 1 &&  isblank { buffer[++n] = $0 }
state == 1 && !isblank { for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) print buffer[i]; n = 0; print }
```

`state` denotes what state the program is in.  When `state == 0`, the program will remove any blank line.  A blank line is a line that is empty or that only contains spaces or tabs (which is what `[[:blank:]]` matches). The program stays in `state == 0` until a non-blank line is found.  This trims the beginning of the file.

When `state == 1`, the program will save blank lines into the `buffer` array.  These blank lines needs to be outputted as soon as a non-blank line is found.  If no non-blank line is found, they will be discarded (this trims the end of the file).

The overall effect is that blank lines at the start and end of the file are removed, while blank lines elsewhere are preserved (including their spaces or tabs, if they contained these in the original file).

Testing:

```
$ cat file



Three blank lines above


Two blank lines in the middle
Three blank lines below



$ awk -f trim.awk file
Three blank lines above


Two blank lines in the middle
Three blank lines below
```

The program does not modify blanks at the start of the first non-blank line nor at the end of the last non-blank line. If that is needed, one could use

```
$ awk -f trim.awk file | sed -e '1s/^[[:blank:]]*//' -e '$s/[[:blank:]]*$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ed which unfortunately don't came in standard install of debian.

```
printf '%s\n' \
 'g/[^[:blank:]][^[:blank:]]*/kx' \
 "'"'x,$j' \
 '$s/[[:blank:]]*$//' \
 '/[^[:blank:]][^[:blank:]]*/kx' \
 '1,'"'"'xj' \
 '1s/^[[:blank:]]*//' \
 'wq' | 
ed -s infile
```

Or with gnu sed

```
sed -Ezi 's/^\s+|\s+$//g;s/$/\n/' infile
```